# How do I change this code to show all quests with a lower level than my character in game?

Tags: lua

This addon for world of warcraft written in lua can track quest  up to 6 levels lower than the current level om my character, and show them on the map. 
The creator of this addon stated in a forum that we can change this to show all quests that are lower than the current character level by just changing the code in the files. 
I have tried and tried with different numbers and operators, but I am not a programmer, I have not goten it to work as I want to, so I turn here for a helping hand.

How do I change this line of code to show me all quest lower than my characters level on the in game map?

```
function Questie:addAvailableQuests()
local mapid = getCurrentMapID();
local level = UnitLevel("Player");
for l=level-6,level do --this line
```

Comment: `for l=0,level do --this line `

Comment: Thankyou for the quick answer, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Show all the code of that addon

Comment: I am not usre if that is possible. 
The file contains over 1346 lines of code.

The function I posted was the only one that contained the number -6
and it was on line number 915.

Comment: Then please post only the function (but the **whole** function), if that's shorter than a few thousand lines of code. Alternatively, post the whole code on a service like pastebin

Comment: I did as you said and posted it on pastebin.

[link](http://pastebin.com/DrTHj53n)

Comment: Nothing I did on that line of code seemed to have any effect in game what so ever. I changed it to +10, +50, and I even commented out the whole line of code, but nothing changed in the game. 
And I did save the edit and restared the game, so It shoulod have updated properly.

Comment: @ravinki - Your problem is how to apply changes you've made.  Ask on warcraft forum.

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
I will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Egor but it could be:

```
for l=1,level do --this line
```

As LUA has 1-based indexing and I imagine the rest of the code uses the l counter as the index of the quest list. If that doesn't work please post the rest of the function. I would comment above but I do not have above 50 rep yet.

Comment: Lua does allow arbitrary table indices.  It depends on the game.  In some games (example: Dungeon Siege 1) a player starts with level 0.  I don't know whether player levels in Warcraft are starting from 1 or from 0.